# Jboss-eap-6.3 Could not reserve enough space for object heap

Tags: java, jboss6.x

I have Java7 running on 32-bit Windows.
When I am running Jboss-eap-6.3 server, I am getting the following exception repeatedly each time I try to run the program.

- `D:\mysoft\jboss-eap-6.3\bin>standalone.bat`
- Calling `D:\mysoft\jboss-eap-6.3\bin\standalone.conf.bat`
- Setting JAVA property to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_10\bin\java`

---

```
JBoss Bootstrap Environment
JBOSS_HOME: "D:\mysoft\jboss-eap-6.3"
JAVA: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_10\bin\java"

JAVA_OPTS: "-verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=5 -XX:GCLogFileSize=3M -XX:-Tra
ceClassUnloading -client -Dprogram.name=standalone.bat -Xms1G -Xmx1G -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true  -Djboss.modules.policy-per
missions=true  -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman"

...
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Can any one help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's actually a problem with the startup script. Here's the bug for that https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=956281. The workaround is to remove the **perm gen** setting from the `JAVA_OPTS` line:

```
Cause: The max perm gen space parameter is causing the JVM to not be created, which then prevents the server from starting.  This is specifically on Windows 8 32-bit JVM.
Consequence: The server will not start.
Workaround (if any): Remove the -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
```

Answer (score 6):

You can also resolve this by changing JAVA_OPTS value under standalone.conf.bat.

old

```
rem # JVM memory allocation pool parameters - modify as appropriate.
set "JAVA_OPTS=-Xms1303M -Xmx1303M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M"
```

new

```
set "JAVA_OPTS=-Xms256M -Xmx256M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M"
```

Answer (score 2):

What is the memory available with your machine?
I see the parameters `-Xms1G -Xmx1G`. This means that your JVM will be started with `Xms=1GB` amount of memory and will be able to use a maximum of `Xmx=1GB` amount of memory.

I think, may be you reduce the amount of memory (like `-Xmx2048m -Xms256m`).

I hope it helps.

You can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14763079/what-are-the-xms-and-xmx-parameters-when-starting-jvms).

Answer (score 1):

According to the above  Federico Sierra answer  under 
`jboss-eap-6.3\domain\configuration` location `host.xml` file is present. In that file I just commented the following line:

```
<permgen size="256m" max-size="256m"/>
```

It's working. Thanks Federico Sierra.

Comment: Please don't post an "answer" to comment on another answer.  If @federicosierra's answer helped you then (upvote and) mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

If it still doesn't work after trying all above options.
Go To:
jboss-eap-6.4\domain\configuration -> host.xml, and have this size set up

```
<heap size="256m" max-size="256m"/>
```

And also go to:
jboss-eap-6.4\standalone\configuration -> standalone.xml, have this size set up

```
set "JAVA_OPTS=-Xms256M -Xmx256M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M"
```

And now Restart your Eclipse and try Run your Jboss6.1+ server it should be working.

Also set this in `host.xml: <permgen size="256m" max-size="256m"/>`
Good Luck.

Comment: Also set this in host.xml: <permgen size="256m" max-size="256m"/>

Answer (score 0):

For me its worked by switching to 64bit JDK... When I was using 32 bit jdk I was facing this issue