# JBoss EAP 6.3 Error :: Error occurred during initialization of VM. Could not reserve enough space for object heap

Tags: jboss, java-8, eclipse-luna, jboss-eap-6

I am using Java 8 (32 bit) on 32 bit windows 7 machine. RAM on machine is 3GB.

Whenever I am trying to start JBoss EAP 6.3 server in Eclipse Luna, it gives me below error,

```
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 1048576KB object heap
```

I have commented below code from host.xml file located in "jboss-eap-6.3\domain\configuration" path

```
<permgen size="256m" max-size="256m"/>
```

But still gives me same error.

Also I found that, Permanent Generation is removed from Java 8 and it is replaced by Metaspace. How can I make changes for this? How can I overcome this issue?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26356305/jboss-eap-6-3-could-not-reserve-enough-space-for-object-heap

Answer (score 0):

Jboss EAP 6.3 not support Java 8, so even if you can run it on Java 8 it may be cause of many issues .
https://developer.jboss.org/message/877474?_sscc=t